# Single quotes becomes double quotes when I read from file

Tags: python

I have this problem.  I read simple text file with some information and then I append additional information to that string and write to new file.
It works, but when some of my strings have single double quotes around some parts python writes back with double double quotes.

```
import sys,os,csv

def write(output):

    with open (outputfilename, 'a') as f:
         writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter = '|', lineterminator = '\r\n')
         writer.writerows(output)

dic_one = {} # some dict with values

def get_val(i,id):

    for k,v in dict_one.items():
        keys_list = k.split('-')
        if int(id) == int(keys_list[-2]):
            if id in keys_list:
                value = v
                del dict_one[k]
                return value



with open(org_file, 'r') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
         temp_list = []
         id = line[0:3]
         second_string = get_val(i, id)
         output_line = line + second_string

         # reason why I am using lists is because my systems throws permission denied errors, due to restrictions on folder.
         # i keep all records in memory and then write them as i get to my last line

         temp_list.append(output_line)
         write_list.append(temp_list)

         if i == 60000-1:
             write(output_list)
             output_list = []
```

From this my string becomes:

```
string = 1234 test test "test" test
```

desired output is: **1234 test test "test" test values from dict_one**

output in 4-5 cases out of 60K lines is:

**"1234 test test ""test"" test values from dict_one"**

This happens only in lines where " is present.
Thanks for your effort!

Comment: Please show us the exact contents of a file that shows that problem. Also show the code for `get_val()`. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: How are you testing the content of the variable?

Comment: I have created another code that tests the length of the lines, and out of 60K lines, 4-5 lines with quotes will have this double double quotes.

Comment: Your code doesn't have any print or write statements. How are you determining that the values are wrong? How are you writing the file?

Comment: I have added missing code here.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the issue must be in get_val() - python itself will not randomly add quotes when reading or writing to files.

Comment: Well out of 60K records only 4-5 records will have double double quotes when original file has single quotes in file

Comment: What about here ? output_line = line + second_string.  Double quotes appear in the output_line